# How to debug a WCF hosted by a windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, windows-services

I have a WCF service and it is hosted in a Windows Service (Not IIS) I created.

I have created a client console app and it installed on a different PC.

I have tested it all and the WCF method is invoked OK by the client.

Normally, i host my WCF under IIS and I would normally attach to the w3wp.exe process and debug it.

What process do I attach when it is hosted by my web service?

I have tried attaching to the service exe but the breakpoint did not get hit.

So, my question is how do I debug my WCF under a Windows Service?

Thanks

Comment: Attaching to the service exe file is the correct thing to do. Are you attaching to the remote machine? Did you copy the .pdb file across?

Comment: Hi I am debugging directly on the PC hosting the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should just attach to service that you created on remote PC. To check all services that is installed on remote PC go:

> Contoll panel -> Administrating -> Services

Just find your service there and you can connect to it.

Comment: Hi, yes thanks for the info. I did know about this but the debugger does not attach. Maybe I need to uninstall service and reinstall just in case versioning is different

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Version of remote debugger that installed on server match Version that your VS can handle?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson sometimes it helps to reinstall remote debugger on your remote machine.

Comment: Hi I am not using a remote debugger I am debugging directly on the PC. I shall uninstall and reinstall...

Comment: uh, i get it, then why you need to attach? You can just start in debug multile projects in VS. Do you know it?

Comment: Hi, yes I do but my client app is on another PC and I am trying to attach directly on the hosting PC the connection coming through